# Why doesn't my browser make a difference between classes and ids in my thread?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well this is a kind of a hard question to ask, but i guess you will see why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #player {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        .obstacle {
            border-radius: 1em;
            background-color: #663300;
            width: 100px;
            height: 75px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            margin-top: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div class="obstacle"></div>
    <script> 
        $('body').css('cursor', 'none');
        /*$("#player").click(function() {
            var position = $("#circle").offset();
            alert(position);
        });
        $("#player").draggable(); */
        $(document).mousemove(function(event){ 
            var X = event.pageX;
            var Y = event.pageY;
            $("#player").css('margin-top', Y-75);
            $("#player").css('margin-left', X-75);
            //alert(X+" "+Y);
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code should create a div with an id of "player", then place it wherever your cursor currently is. (that works just fine) But then there is the "obstacle" which for some reason moves along with the player, although it shouldn't.

Why is this happenning? Could someone explain it to me?

A picture:[image]

Comment: This 'could' be a CSS issue rather than JS.. Have you tried applying a position:fixed/absolute on the obstacle?

Comment: you changing `margin`s which affects that block size, so bottom blocks moving too. try to change `top` and `left` instead and set it's `position` to `absolute`

Comment: Tried it, didn't fix it... So this could be a problem with css? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @llamerr Thanks, that did it :) , didn't even think about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/fq4y4r41/

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'none');
/*$("#player").click(function() {
 var position = $("#circle").offset();
 alert(position);
 });
 $("#player").draggable(); */
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var X = event.pageX;
    var Y = event.pageY;
    $("#player").css('top', Y-75);
    $("#player").css('left', X-75);
    //alert(X+" "+Y);
});
```

and css

```
#player {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

you changing margins which affects that block size, so bottom blocks moving too. try to change top and left instead and set it's position to absolute

that way you move that element away from flow - https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to move a block based on mouse movement, I think you might have to use a different position value, like absolute

```
#player {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```js
$('body').css('cursor', 'none');
 /*$("#player").click(function() {
     var position = $("#circle").offset();
     alert(position);
 });
 $("#player").draggable(); */
 $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
   var X = event.pageX;
   var Y = event.pageY;
   $("#player").css('margin-top', Y - 75);
   $("#player").css('margin-left', X - 75);
   //alert(X+" "+Y);
 });
```

```css
#player {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: green;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 100px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .obstacle {
      border-radius: 1em;
      background-color: #663300;
      width: 100px;
      height: 75px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="obstacle"></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nr9p1ybx/)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change the css

```
#player {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: green;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5ptcdxt/). Checkit out :)